# Compiling Ogre with LibTiff - undefined reference

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, ogre, libtiff

I need to compile ogre as a dependency for gazebo with RoS. During the linking of it I get the following errors:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/SampleBrowser
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/libfreeimage.so: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEncodedStrip@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../lib/libfreeimage.so: undefined reference to `TIFFReadEXIFDirectory@LIBTIFF_4.0'
...
```

These errors seem to be caused by missing **libtiff5**. Even after installing libtiff5, libtiff5-dev and libtiff4, libtiff4-dev it doesn't get picked up by the linker. I installed libtiff 4.0.3 by source and I think my system is now so cluttered that it always takes the wrong version of the library.

```
ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep libtiff
```

gives me:

```
libtiff.a
libtiff.la
libtiff.so
libtiff.so.4
libtiff.so.4.3.6
libtiff.so.5
libtiff.so.5.2.0
libtiffxx.a
libtiffxx.la
libtiffxx.so
libtiffxx.so.0
libtiffxx.so.0.0.10
libtiffxx.so.5
libtiffxx.so.5.2.0
```

Running debian jessie x64.

Answer (score 0):

The official Ogre3D dependencies (that can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/cabalistic/ogredeps)) are currently based on *FreeImage 3.15.3* which internally is based on *LibTIFF 4.0.1*.

Using those versions might solve your issues.